# Reading from a certain line until there is no more content in Java

Tags: java

I would like to read and display the content of a text file from a set line(In this case line 13) until the end of the text file.
So if the document has 20 lines, it should display line 13 to 20. The problem is, that this document gets more content and therefore the number of lines should be determined automatically.

Basically it needs to end when there is no more content. If I do not set an end line, the output is "null" forever.

```
       try {

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt"));
            String info = "";
            int startLine = 13;
            int endLine = 25;
            System.out.println(""); 

            for (int x = 0; x < startLine; x++) {
                info = in.readLine(); 
              }                  


            for (int x = startLine; x < endLine + 1; x++) {
                info = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(info);                   
            }
            System.out.println("");
            in.close();
        }
            catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this to setup a loop. It will continue to read until it encounters a null, which would be the end of the file.

```
while ((info = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! Works how it should :)

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept one of the answers for the next guy who encounters the problem!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you could do it with something like this -

```
for (int x = 0; x < startLine; x++) {
  info = in.readLine();
}

while ((info = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(info);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Good fix.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
  BufferedReader in = null;
  try {

       in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt"));
        String info = null;
        int startLine = 13;
        int lineNum = 0;

        while ((info = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNum++;
            if (lineNum >= startLine) {
                 System.out.println(info);                   
            }
        }

    }
        catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       in.close();
    }
```

Also, be sure to close the reader in a finally block.

You may also want to look a [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)

Comment: Poster wanted it to read to the end of the file. This will stop printing after `endLine` has been reached and continue to read the file into memory needlessly.

Comment: Sorry, edited to print to the end. I thought poster had endLine=25 because he wanted to only print lines 13 to 25. If the file was only 15 lines ling it would have printed to the eof.